# django in production enviorment, urls.py only matching empty path i.e " " and nothing else?

Tags: python, django

Everything works fine on development server but in production server I can only access views.home at https://www.host.com/ and everything else such as
https://www.host.com/b/ or https://www.host.com/tab or https://www.host.com/ext returns status_code 500.

I'm using django 2.1 in python 3.7. Cheers!

Here's the project level urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from ext.forms import CustomAuthForm
from mysite import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(authentication_form = CustomAuthForm), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page= settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL), name='logout'),
    path('', include('ext.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And app level urls.py looks like this

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from ext import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'ext'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('int/', views.get_int_status, name='home-load-int'),
    path('ext/', views.get_ext_status, name='home-load-ext'),
    path('tab/', views.get_tab_status, name='home-load-tab'),
    path('b/', views.uzair, name='home-uzair'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `RewriteEngine On` in my .httaccess file, what a shame xD